# Exoplayer: How to play audio through ear piece?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, exoplayer

I'm currently using following code to switch the audio stream to ear piece when the device gets close to any object:

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    if (mAudioManager.isWiredHeadsetOn() || !(mCurrentPlaybackStatus == STATUS_PLAYING
            || mCurrentPlaybackStatus == STATUS_PREPARING)) {
        return;
    }

    boolean isClose = event.values[0] < mSensor.getMaximumRange();

    if (!mScreenDisabled && isClose) {

        mAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mAudioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);

        disableScreen();

        mScreenDisabled = true;

    } else if (mScreenDisabled && !isClose) {

        mAudioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
        mAudioManager.setMode(mAudioManagerMode);

        enableScreen();
        mScreenDisabled = false;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately there is a significant delay when calling `.setMode(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);` (> 500ms)

With Android's default MediaPlayer the output stream can be changed without delay:

```
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL); // ear piece
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC); // speakerphone
```

Is there any way to change ExoPlayer's output stream?

Answer (score 2):

For changing **ExoPlayer's stream type**, you need to pass the stream type through the MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer constructor, into (ExoPlayer's) AudioTrack constructor,

```
  public AudioTrack() {
    this(null, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);   //default is STREAM_MUSIC
  }

  public AudioTrack(AudioCapabilities audioCapabilities, int streamType) {

  }
```

So in your application, you'll specify the type when you build the renderer.

Please refer https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/755 for more info

Comment: Is it possible to change the stream type during play?

Comment: You cannot change stream type during play. On earlier version of exo player ONLY STREAM_MUSIC was allowed. Now they have given the flexibility to use different stream types.

Comment: @timoschloesser
You can change it during play, I posted my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Play through the ear piece

```
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);
```

Comment: This is not related to ExoPlayer.

Comment: @timoschloesser, actually it IS related to ExoPlayer if mediaPlayer is an instance of SimpleExoPlayer :) https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/270f68a/library/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/SimpleExoPlayer.java#L300

Answer (score 0):

In exoPlayer, I solved it by these:
Use this function to change the speaker to ear piece

```
audioPlayer.setAudioStreamType(C.STREAM_TYPE_VOICE_CALL);
```

and vise versa(using the phone speaker)

```
audioPlayer.setAudioStreamType(C.STREAM_TYPE_MUSIC);
```

But in newer versions of exoPlayer, this function has been deleted. Instead of that use this:

```
fun setAttributes(@C.StreamType streamType: Int) {
    @AudioUsage val usage = Util.getAudioUsageForStreamType(streamType)
    @AudioContentType val contentType =
        Util.getAudioContentTypeForStreamType(streamType)
    val audioAttributes =
        AudioAttributes.Builder().setUsage(usage).setContentType(contentType).build()
    audioPlayer.setAudioAttributes(audioAttributes, false)
}
```

And finally call the function:

```
setAttributes(C.STREAM_TYPE_VOICE_CALL)
```

or

```
setAttributes(C.STREAM_TYPE_MUSIC)
```